# Android - equivalent of UITableViewCell?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

Is there an equivalent of a `UITableViewCell`for a `RecyclerView` or (any other recyclable view) in Android ? None of my searches have given me any direction. Some help would be really appreciated.

I understand that a `RecyclerView` has a position that corresponds to a row in the case of a list. But is this correct, is this the equivalent of `UITableViewCell` in Android ?

Comment: Why do you want a `UITableViewCell` equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent of a UITableViewCellfor a RecyclerView or (any
>   other recyclable view) in Android ?

Yes.

*`UITableViewCell` is equivalent of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`*

Because [Apple's API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell) says:

> **UITableViewCell** class defines the attributes and behavior of the cells that appear in `UITableView` objects

and in same way, [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) say:

> **RecyclerView.ViewHolder** describes an item view and metadata about its place within the RecyclerView.